# SignalR AspNetCore v1.0.0: working directly with Connection object

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

We have a Signalr .NET application using directly the underlying Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Connection class  (parent of the HubConnection class) for more low level usage. Now we don't see it anymore in AspNetCore SignalR: it looks you may only work with Hubs. Is there any alternative way to work directly in the .net core framework with a Connection object as we can do SignalR 2.x for .NET?

Here a very basic sample:

```
public class DiagnosticsConnection : PersistentConnection
{
    protected override Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)
    {
        if (String.Equals(data, "PING", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            Connection.Send(connectionId, "PONG");

        return base.OnReceived(request, connectionId, data);
    }
}
```

In .NET based SignalR (not the .NET Core/Standard) we could directly send different (and not strongly typed) messages to clients.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve in the first place?

Comment: We are moving our server side from .NET to dotnetcore. We need to work at connection level as we manage externally the logic as "which client has to be broadcasted with message X". Than we need to handle all different case of connection status. So we do work with Hubs. BTW we use RabbitMq as message storage.

Comment: "Than we need to handle all different case of connection status. So we do work with Hubs." That didn't make sense. Can you show code that worked, and code that you're trying to make work?

Comment: Sorry typo ... we do NOT work with hubs.

Comment: Show how you (used and) would use a `Connection` that wouldn't work with a `Hub`.

Comment: Edit your question to ask one question.

Comment: It'll be back in the next version. We didn't have time to fix the API so it was made internal.

Comment: @davidfowl, thanks, BTW are you talking about version 2.x? Any idea when it will be available?

Comment: The low-level connection API is present in the .NET client, but not the JavaScript client. It's available through the HttpConnection class. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @AndrewStanton-Nurse: I just added a basic sample in the question to show how we use PersistenConnection in .NET SignalR